# Nested Firestore listeners and how to unsubscribe from created listeners

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use a nested listener structure like this one:

```js
snapshotListeners() {
  firestore()
    .collectionGroup()
    .where()
    .onSnapshot({
      error: //Handle error
      next: firstSnapshot => {
        firstSnapshot.docsChanges().forEach(change => {
          //Data retrieved and used in the below query to get more data
          firestore()
            .collection()
            .where() //using the data retrived from the above query here.
            .onSnapshot({
              error: //Handle error
              next: secondSnapshot => {
                secondSnapshot.docsChanges().forEach(change =>{
                  //More Data from second query
                })
              }
            })
        })
      }
    })
}
```

which is a borrowed snippet from [Nesting firestore onSnapshot listeners in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793199/nesting-firestore-onsnapshot-listeners-in-react-native)

I am unsure how best to keep track of the listeners created when the outer listener fires. How can I unsubscribe the previous inner listener when a new inner listener is created? Would overwriting an old listener's variable unsubscribe it? i.e

```js
 var unsubscribe = old_listener 

 unsubscribe = new_listener
  // would this unsubscribe old listener?
```

If not, then what's a good way to keep track of them? Frank hints at using a list which makes sense but I'm a Javascript beginner and not sure how to implement it. I can append each new listener to a list but how would I then call them as a function to unsubscribe?

Comment: I'm using react and think I got a solution by storing the unsubscribe function in my state which is constructed with a null variable. Every time the outer listener triggers, the state gets called which does nothing if null or unsubscribe if it contains a listener detach function. The state is then overwritten with the new listener function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by first declaring `var unsub` as a dummy function. I used `unsub = () => {}` which returns undefined. I then declare my outer listener which when triggered will call `unsub` before assigning `unsub` to my new inner listener, i.e. `unsub = firestore().collection(..).OnSnapshot()...`. This ensures that each time the outer listener triggers, the previous inner listener is detached before attaching a new listener.

Comment: i know this is a long time ago.. But your answer is not very clear to me.. Care to elaborate on the structure here?

Answer (score 1):

```
firestore.collection().onSnapshot()
```

will return a unsubscribe function. Declare the unsubscribe variable and assign the onSnapshot to it.

After that, you can unsubscribe by calling the function.

e.g,

```
const unsubscribe = firestore.collection("collection_name")
        .onSnapshot(() => { 
// call another snapshot or handle the snapshot data
});
```

When you are done, just unsubscribe by

```
unsubscribe();
```

You can find more examples at [Firestore unsubscribe to updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157997/firestore-unsubscribe-to-updates#:%7E:text=The%20firestore.,and%20you%20should%20be%20guchi.)

Comment: Hi, so this I think I understand. My problem is that the outer listener creates a new inner listener each time itself is triggered and I want to unsubscribe the old inner listener once I get the new inner listener. I don't know how I'd get a unique const name for each created listener