# Detach a Firestore listener inside an onAuthStateChanged listener

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I think I understand how to detach a listener by returning it, but in this specific case I'm not sure of the best way to do it.

I have a React component where I subscribe to auth changes with `onAuthStateChanged`.

If it returns an user : I create a listener to the data of this user in Firestore.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        const unsubscribeFirestore = firebase.db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .onSnapshot(doc => {
            setUser({ user, ...doc.data() })
          })
      } else {
        setUser({ user })
      }
    })
  }, [firebase])
```

Where and how should I return `unsubscribeFirestore` to detach it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370224/firebase-stop-listening-onauthstatechanged

Comment: does it unsubscribe automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code already is implicitly returning the `unsubscribe` callback from `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged`, but you can make it more imperative by capturing the returned `unsubscribe` function in a locally scoped variable.

You can capture the inner snapshot unsubscribe in a React ref to be accessed in the `useEffect` cleanup function.

```
const snapShotUnsubscribeRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      snapShotUnsubscribeRef.current = firebase.db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
          setUser({ user, ...doc.data() })
        })
    } else {
      setUser({ user })
    }
  });

  return () => {
    snapShotUnsubscribeRef.current?.();
    // Or if you can't use Optional Chaining:
    //   snapShotUnsubscribeRef.current && snapShotUnsubscribeRef.current()
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, [firebase]);
```

Comment: Thanks, yes for `onAuthStateChanged` I understand that the return works, it's more for the second listener `firebase.db.collection.doc.onSnapshot` that I'm not sure if just return `unsubscribe` detach it too.

Comment: @uciska IMO it isn't necessary but to be honest, I can't find docs specific to this. I'll update my answer to capture both in the outer scope to be invoked in the effect cleanup function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) to the official Firebase docs for more details.

The answer Drew gave is correct. To add I don't think you need to worry about the nested second listener since the if clause is checking if there is a user or not and if there is none then the second listener does not apply anyway. You can try both use cases to test if it is working or not.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987665/nested-firestore-listeners-and-how-to-unsubscribe-from-created-listeners) dealing with this use case. So this should work.