# Nested onSnapshot problem in react-native-Firebase Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm struggling to overcome problems that I have on nested `onSnapshot`, so, in short, I have 3 nested  `onSnapshot` and when parent/root `onSnapshot` updates it also creates new `onSnapshot` listeners and leaves old ones too, so old and new ones are listening to the changes. I know that I should unsubscribe it but I can't, I'm losing track of which listeners are added or already exist.

One solution is to create array of unsubscribing functions in parent `onSnapshot`, but there another problem comes, I'm using  `docChanges` with `forEach` and it is hard to manage which would I unsubscribe from array.

I saw this on Stackoverflow but it doesn't fit mine or even doesn't explain correctly exactly this case: [nested listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987665/nested-firestore-listeners-and-how-to-unsubscribe-from-created-listeners)

What can you suggest to me? I don't know what else should I do.

Thanks in advance.

here is an example of my code that I'm trying to implement unsubscribe stuff( I use Mobx):

```
 // TODO: optimise this query
      const id = auth().currentUser?.uid;

      // get all channelId-s that user has
      channelParticipantsRef
        .where('user.id', '==', id)
        .onSnapshot((userChannels) => {
       

          userChannels?.docChanges().forEach(function (channelParticipant) {
            const channelParticipantData = channelParticipant;

            if (!channelParticipantData.doc.exists) return;

            // get all channels data that user has
            channelsRef
              .where(
                'channelId',
                '==',
                channelParticipantData.doc.data().channelId,
              )
              .onSnapshot((channels) => {
                if (!channels || channels.empty) return;

                channels.docChanges().forEach(function (channel) {
                  const channelDataObject = channel.doc.data();

                  console.logBeauty(channel.type, 'channelDataObject ');

                  if (channel.type === 'added' || channel.type === 'modified') {
                    const channelData: ChannelTransformedDataType = {
                      ...channelDataObject,
                      language: channelParticipantData.doc.data().language,
                      channelParticipantId: channelParticipantData.doc.id,
                      lastMessageDate: {
                        ...channelDataObject.lastMessageDate,
                      },
                      otherUsers: [],
                    };

                    // get all channels users
                    channelParticipantsRef
                      .where('user.id', '!=', id)
                      .where('channelId', '==', channelDataObject.channelId)
                      .onSnapshot((channelParticipants) => {
                        const participants: UserModelType[] = [];

                        if (channelParticipants.empty)
                          return self.removeChannel(
                            channelDataObject.channelId,
                          );

                        channelParticipants.docs.forEach(
                          (channelParticipant) => {
                            participants.push(channelParticipant.data().user);
                          },
                        );

                        channelData.otherUsers = participants;

                        console.log(channelData, 'channelDatachannelData');

                        if (channel.type === 'added')
                          self.pushChannel(channelData);
                        else self.editChannel(channelData);
                      });
                  } else if (channel.type === 'removed') {
                    self.removeChannel(channelDataObject.channelId);
                  }
                });
              });
          });
        });
```

Comment: Please share the code that you've tried.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I updated it, I need help in managing how to unsubscribe old listeners.